# javascript catch errors on function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In `Java` methods can use the keyword `throws Exception` and all errors are thrown when you call the method, this reduce the uses of try catch

I'm learning `JavaScript` now, but I find hard to believe that there's no similar keyword in `JavaScript`, are we suppose to surround everything with try-catch blocks?

I find myself checking every variable like this

`if(packet.username && packet.password && packet.id && packet.errors)`

followed by checking the type of all this vars

and using a lot of try catch blocks which make the code very large and unclear

I find it annoying really, is there a way to handle any errors and catching them in the main function call?

**Edit: since it been 3 answers and all of them are misunderstanding the question, sorry about that, English isn't my first language**

I don't want to know how to throw an exception, take this java vs javascript example

I'm programming a server which should handle all kinds of errors, now if an error occurs is most certainly a client is sending its own custom data that server don't expect....

In java, I would do something like this

```
try{
    // I only need to try catch here....
    parsePacket();
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.print();
}

void parsePacket() throws Exception{
    //.....
    // a lot of more possible errors here mainly the ones the server doesn't expect....
    //.....
    anotherFunction();
    //imagine a lot of more functions here that can throw an error
}

void anotherFunction() throws Exception{
    //.....
    // a lot of more posible errors here....
    //.....
}
```

How pretty? just one try-catch block, however in javascript I find myself doing this

JavaScript

```
try{

    parsePacket();
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.print();
}

void parsePacket(){
    try{
        //for some reason I have to catch TypeErrors and other ones here too
        //.....
        // a lot of more posible errors
        //.....
        anotherfunction(()=>{
            try{
                //.....
                // a lot of more posible errors here
                //.....
            }
            catch(err){

            }
        })
    }
    catch(err){

    }
}

void anotherFunction(){
    try{
        //.....
        // a lot of more posible errors here
        //.....
    }
    catch(err){

    }
}
```

**And it can get ugly pretty fast**

Comment: The best approach is to minimize try/catch handling by proper checking. It is true pain when somebody before you wrote app, it stops working and it doesnt print anything. Then you go, row by row and after two hours you realize that on row 2347 is empty catch block..

Comment: Two comments: Java is pretty much the only language that does that "declare all exceptions" business, which is hated by a lot of people; runtime exceptions can be thrown without declaring them in method signature, so you wouldn't have complete list of exception anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are working on, if you are working with nodejs and not limited to importing libraries/packages you could try **indicative** where in here you can indicate sets of rules to validate your json. Please see reference [indicative](https://indicative.adonisjs.com/)

```
const { validate } = require('indicative')

const rules = {
  email: 'required|email|unique:users',
  password: 'required|min:6|max:30'
}

const data = {
  email: 'foo@bar.com',
  password: 'weak'
}

validate(data, rules)
  .then(() => {
  })
  .catch((errors) => {
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

In `JavaScript`, exception handling works bit differently than `Java`. You need to define your exceptions for each case (type check) and `throw` that exception if case matches, then that exception will be cached in `catch` block.

Example of `type check` from official docs:

```js
function getRectArea(width, height) {
  if (isNaN(width) || isNaN(height)) {
    throw "Parameter is not a number!";
  }
}

try {
  getRectArea(3, 'A');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  // expected output: "Parameter is not a number!"
}
```

For more details about **`throw statement`** please check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: please see my edit, since I think you misunderstood the question

Comment: @centenond I think I understood your question correctly. Answer is my second sentence ***You need to define your exceptions for each case** (type check) and throw that exception if case matches, then that exception will be cached in catch block* so you need to add checks by yourself. It is not like Java where exceptions and types are handled by `Exception.*` package. Above is pure JavaScript solution which I am using in my node.js project.

Comment: this means I still need to check all of the variables? :c

Comment: @centenond unfortunately yes you have to :)

Answer (score 1):

You can throw anything without declaring:

```
function foo() {
  throw {hello: 'world'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one **try** and a series of **catch** aroung the whole script

```
try {
    if(packet.username && packet.password && packet.id && packet.errors)
    //all the other code
}
catch(err) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = err.message;
}
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```